# TypeError: string indices must be integerss

Tags: dataframe

```
c = [requests.get(i['link'], auth=(username, password)).json()['result']['name'] for i in df['assigned_to']]
```

I am expecting name value when i hit the link but i am facing error.

> TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Comment: We won't be able to tell you the exact error if you don't show us the input data.

Comment: c = [requests.get(i['link'], auth=(username, password)).json()['result']['name'] for i in df['assigned_to']]
print(c)
df=df.assign(assigned_to=c)
print(df)

Comment: 1. that's not the data from the request 2. update the question instead of adding a comment